# What fireball does the red magical shark fin increase damage on?

Tags: candy-box-2

The Red Magical Shark Fin says that it greatly increases the damage of the fireball spell. Does this also include the fireballs cast by red enchanted gloves and the Octopus King Crown enchanted with Jaspers or just the Fireball spell that you select during a quest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Red Magical Shark Fin affects all fireballs cast, including the ones from the red enchanted gloves, the Octopus King Crown enchanted with Jaspers, and the normal fireball spell.

Source: My own testing.